# aJoin on three tables with like statment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables student,subject and marks.
Student

```
Student
id,name,address
1,tom,London
2,sam,USA
3,cal,Fort

subject
id,subjectname
1,maths
2,Science

marks
studid,subid,marks
1,1,30
1,2,40
2,1,60
2,2,70
```

Need to have a search query on students and subjects
so i am using a like query on students `LIKE CONCAT('%', "cal", '%')`

```
    SELECT student.name,
        subject.name,
       marks.marks
  FROM marks
  RIGHT JOIN student ON student.name LIKE CONCAT('%', "cal", '%') AND student.id = marks.stuid 
 RIGHT JOIN subject ON subject.id = marks.subjectid
```

Need an output like this while searching for student

```
Studentname subject Marks
cal,maths,0
cal,science,0

Studentname subject Marks
tom,maths,30
tom,science,40

Studentname subject Marks
sam,maths,60
sam,science,70
```

I need both all subject and all students as well If no values are passed all should be seen

```
Studentname subject Marks
tom,maths,30
tom,science,40    
sam,maths,60
sam,science,70
cal,maths,0
cal,science,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all subjects.  So, start with that and use `left join`:

```
SELECT s.name, su.name, coalesce(m.marks, 0)
FROM subjects su LEFT JOIN
     marks m
     ON m.subjectid = su.id LEFT JOIN
     student s
     ON s.name LIKE CONCAT('%', 'cal', '%') AND
        s.id = m.stuid ;
```

If you need all students and subjects, then start with a `cross join`:

```
SELECT s.name, su.name, coalesce(m.marks, 0)
FROM subjects su CROSS JOIN
     students s LEFT JOIN
     marks m
     ON m.subjectid = su.id AND s.id = m.stuid ;
```

Comment: Its giving this output
name name coalesce(m.marks, 0)  
NULL maths  30
NULL science  40
NULL maths  60
NULL science  70

Comment: I need both all subject and all students as well If no values are passed all should be seen

Answer (score 1):

Here may be what you want

```
SELECT student.name,
        subject.name,
        IFNULL(marks.marks,0) 

FROM (student JOIN subject) left join marks on student.id = marks.studid and subject.id = marks.subid
where student.name LIKE CONCAT('%', "cal", '%')
```

Comment: When I run this I get 0 rows.

Comment: I have change answer, I think that is what you want